# Php inside html file will not execute

Tags: php, html, css

So I have some PHP stuff inside my html doc, and I'm fairly new to web stuff so I'm kinda confused. The code in question is:

```
   <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background: url(<?php include 'background.php';
                    echo "$selectedBg"; ?>) no-repeat center center fixed;
                background: url(images/1.png)
                background-size: cover;
            }
    </style>
```

The rest of the file works seamlessly, I've tried putting that little bit in all sorts of different tags, and even changing the file to a php file instead of an html one. I've verified that php is installed and my path is correct. background.php exists in the same directory as seen [here](http://puu.sh/jVfuL/42ba4b299d.png), [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) are the sites I referenced when creating it. The only other info I can think to provide is that I'm viewing it through the live preview in Brackets.

Comment: in simple this is now how things work, more detail on it's way

Comment: I don't think live preview in Brackets works with PHP. You'll need to run a local webserver, like XAMPP or MAMP.

Comment: I see you echoing out a string in `echo "$selectedBg"` did you mean it to be a variable here? that might be your problem

Comment: *"and even changing the file to a php file instead of an html one"* - well yeah. If you haven't instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP, you kind of don't have a choice BUT to use a `.php` extension.

Comment: Use .php as extension and run it from a server, for example XAMPP

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan No, that was intended. The purpose of this script was to randomly select a background image, and if you look at the referenced sites it shows you.

Comment: @Shehary Well, that's disappointing. I've seen a few people that have actually done this and had it work exactly how I've done it.

Comment: @PrudhviKonda Changed to .php, hosted with xampp, still doesn't work.

Comment: what does show in source code once loaded in your browser ?

Comment: Can you please try it without the double quotes while echoing selectedBg. make it as echo $selectedBg

Answer (score 1):

Changing the file to a php file fixed it. The whole file now looks like.

```
<html>
    <?php include 'background.php';?>
    <title>Yay</title>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: url(<?php echo $wall;?>);
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

where background.php is

```
<?php
  $bg = array('1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png', '8.png');

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
  $selected = "$bg[$i]";
  $wall = "images/$selected";
?>
```